# How to modify Javascript exception

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to javascript. I am using this http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBPlugin.aspx in mvc3.
I don't need those filters in the above link. If I remove them from my view, I am getting exception. So how to modify the .js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute simplest solution: use CSS `display: none` to hide the elements that you don't want to show.

You could also disable filtering with the `useFilters: false` option. — see [this demo page](http://www.meadmiracle.com/dlb/DLBPluginOptions.aspx).

Comment: BTW, this jQuery plugin has nothing to do with ASP.NET.

Comment: `/shrug` if it works, it works. There's always something to be said for simplicity. See my edit for a "nicer/better" solution.